# Tooltip в прокручиваемом элементе

Tags: html, css

Создал `tooltip` на чистом css. Проблема заключается в том, что он находится в прокручиваемом модальном окне, и не меняет своих координат относительно страницы при прокрутке. То есть все `toolti`p'ы, которые находится в части окна ниже его высоты, не прокручиваются вместе с модальным окном.

**Код:**

```css
.tooltip:before {
  content: "\f059";
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: .8em;
}
.tooltip > span {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-top: 17.5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .9);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tooltip:hover > span,
.tooltip:active > span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition-duration: .7s;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <fieldset>
    <label for="login">Логин <i class="tooltip"><span>Логин должен содержать от 3 до 64 любых символов.</span></i></label>
    <input id="login" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Ikor_Dadurii">

    <label for="password">Пароль <i class="tooltip"><span>Пароль должен содержать от 8 символов. Допустимые символы: латинские буквы, цифры, символы "-" и "_"</span></i></label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="qwerty123">

    <label for="password_2">Повторите пароль</label>
    <input id="password_2" type="password" name="password_2" placeholder="qwerty123">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="text" type="text" name="email" placeholder="test@example.com">

    <label for="realname">Имя</label>
    <input id="realname" type="text" name="realname" placeholder="Валера Орехов">

    <label for="tel">Номер телефона <i class="tooltip"><span>В международном формате.</span></i></label>
    <input id="text" type="text" name="tel" placeholder="+375 XX XXXXXXX">
  </fieldset>
  <button>Зарегистрироваться</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Наверно надо на относительно relative   расположить вашу подсказку

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, к сожалению, есть возможность исключительно абсолютно ее отпозиционировать, иначе она будет влиять на основной поток элементов, а мне это не нужно.